# Asp.Net: Using variable as Update Parameter?

Tags: asp.net, parameters

Is it possible to use a variable as an update parameter in asp.net?

I have the page number to be updated stored in a variable called 'mypagenum', how would I write an update parameter using that value.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1) Using onUpdating event:

```
protected void sqlDataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["@param_name"].Value = mypagenum;
    }
```

2) Setting the default value of the parameter:

```
sqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["param_name"].DefaultValue = mypagenum;
```

SQL Data Source object definition may look like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<some connection string>" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE table SET column = @param_name"
    onUpdating="sqlDataSource1_Updating">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="param_name" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How to set the parameter on row cells value ? Let's say, on the row["id_person"] value ?